# WebBrowser control renders CSS differently than IE11 - Same documentMode

Tags: c#, css, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have noticed a difference between how IE 11 renders this page and the WebBrowser control renders this page.  WebBrowser's emulation mode matches that of IE11, so that is not the issue.  Could this be a defect?

This is how I am setting the WebBrowser object in C#:

```
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
browser.DocumentText = /* I am setting the html here */;
```

If you run this in WebBrowser, you will not see the second line, yet it works perfectly in IE11.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>WebBrowser Rendering Issue</title>
    <style>
        #main-div {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .child-div {
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    You will only see this line rendered in WebBrowser.
    <div id='main-div'>
        <div class='child-div'>
            You will also see this line when ran in IE or Chrome.
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>alert("Document Mode: " + document.documentMode);</script>
</body>
</html>
```